# Removing selected option from dropdown selects default option not next selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am manipulating a select, which before I show is got more than one selected option. After my code just one stays selected, but because I removed the previous selected the select is showing the default instead of the next selected.

```
<body>
    <select id="test"> 
        <option value="1">1 month</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">2 month</option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected">3 month</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

And javascript

```
$('#test option[value=3]').remove();
```

Example here: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/s8j7t2g5/)

Is this expected? In the console the option 2 in the example will still have the selected attribute.

Comment: Can't say for sure but you can't have 2 `selected` attributes in a singular select.

Comment: I guess is like that @tymeJV . Actually, if after removing you try this code: $('#test option:selected') it will give you back 1 month option. I guess the DOM keeps internally just one selected value

Answer (score 0):

It seems its the default behavior. When you mark multiple with `selected` it will make the last one in the list the selected one. After removing the selected item, it will select the first one all the time. No matter if any other items have `selected` attribute or not.

Tested in chrome(38.0.2125.104 m), firefox 31 and ie10. Same behavior everywhere.

Also note that select will pic kthe latest option with select attribute containing whatever.
In case you have:
`<select id="test"> 
        <option value="1">1 month</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">2 month</option>
        <option value="3" selected="false">3 month</option>
    </select>`
Last one will be picked still. Its same for 0, empty string or whatever you put there.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. The funny thing is that if you check in console the plane html, the attribute selected will be there

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt matter at all. I played with various values for selected and if there are more, than 1 it picks the latest one. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Here a fiddle with test and a workaround :

http://jsfiddle.net/s8j7t2g5/9/

The attr of the option is still selected but the val of the select is wrong.

```
$("#test option").each(function () {

    if($(this).attr("selected") == "selected")
    {
        $('#test').val($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. But, after seeing your tests, it seems to me that this is a jquery bug after all!

Comment: At least you have a workaround. Maybe you can find a plugin that support multiple selected value.